# Get all properties for a node magnolia cms

Tags: magnolia

I would like to get a list of properties for a given node in magnolia so that I can get values for each property.

I tried using the PropertyUtil but it cannot find "tags".

```
List<String> tags = info.magnolia.jcr.util.PropertyUtil.getValuesStringList(node.getProperty("tags").getValues());
```

Actual result is `javax.jcr.PathNotFoundException: tags`.
Expected result is a list of properties that I can use to query for property values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is called 'mgnl:tags', please refer to `info.magnolia.contenttags.manager.TagManager#TAGS_PROPERTY`

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do it using javax.jcr Interface Node:

```
PropertyIterator pi = node.getProperties();
while(pi.hasNext())
{
   Property p = pi.nextProperty();
   String name = p.getName();
   String val = p.getString();
}
```